# LWC - Add style attribute from JS

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to dynamically style the LWC progressbar with color and width.
As I cannot assign a JS variable to the style tag in template I try the following in JS:

```
let fleetBarStyle = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="fleetBarId"]');
        console.log('***Fleetbarstyle: ' + fleetBarStyle);
        if(fleetBarStyle){
            fleetBarStyle.style.backgroundcolor ='red';
            fleetBarStyle.style.width = this.approvedFleetPercent <= 100 ? "'" + this.approvedFleetPercent + "'%" : '100%'; 
        }
```

The template part looks like this:

```
<div class="slds-progress-bar slds-progress-bar_large" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow={approvedFleetPercent} role="progressbar">
                            <span data-id="fleetBarId" class="slds-progress-bar__value slds-progress-bar__value_success slds-progress-bar_circular">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: {approvedFleetPercent}</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

The Span tag is found. But I cannot assing the style. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CSS class dynamically in Lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249293/set-css-class-dynamically-in-lightning-web-component)

Comment: Maybe I read it wrong. To add or remove a css class is not the problem what I have. The problem is to assign the percentage of the progress bar, which is calculated in JS to "style="Width:xx%". Which is normally done here: 
<span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width: 100%">

Comment: it comes down to the same, you do it in your js file, and you modify the class that needs to be returned to your element in the template.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, inspired thru your comment. If you create an answer I will mark it as best solution.

Comment: Glad you were able to do so =), posted a code snippet for you to refer to ;). Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to programmatically update a % in class in your template, you will have to do your calculations in your JS file as stated in [Set CSS class dynamically in Lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249293/set-css-class-dynamically-in-lightning-web-component)

Ideally, you want to setup a getter to retrieve the updated value once a percentage attribute has changed. Example:
from the SLDS blueprint code samples:
[Progress Bar Template](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-bar/)

```
<div>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-p-bottom_x-small">
      <span>Percentage Sample</span>
      <span aria-hidden="true">
        <strong>{percentile}% Complete</strong>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-progress-bar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow={percentile} aria-labelledby="progress-bar-label-id-6" role="progressbar">
      <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style={widthPercentage}>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: {percentile}%</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <button class="slds-button" onclick={increase} >+ 1%</button>
    <button class="slds-button" onclick={decrease} >- 1%</button>
  </div>
```

JS File:

```
export default class Progress extends LightningElement {
    tick = 0;

    get percentile(){
        return `${(this.tick / 10)*1}`
    }

    get widthPercentage(){
        return `width:${this.percentile}%`
    }

    increase(){
        this.tick +=10
    }
    decrease(){
        this.tick -=10
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables, you just can't use them inline in the value for a tag's attribute.

Example that does *NOT* work:

```
style="background-color: {legendEntry.color}"
```

where {legendEntry.color} = "#abcdef"

Example that *DOES* work:

```
style={legendEntry.color}
```

where {legendEntry.color} = "background-color: #abcdef"

Hope that helps!